# Flutter Why are SVG images grainy ? (flutter_svg pkg, no anti-aliasing)

Tags: flutter, svg

I'm working on a Flutter application and was trying to insert SVGs into a Sign-up Screen (using [flutter_svg package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg)).
I have noticed that SVGs look grainy, no matter what the mode (mobile / Chrome).

Here is a sample SVG image : [image]

And here is the SVG rendered in Flutter UI (Chrome) :
[image]

As you can see, on browser it looks like we have some aliasing problem?
My asset is in a Container, I have tried playing with height, width, and using `fit: BoxFit.contain`, all to no avail.

```dart
final String assetName = 'dog-shirt.svg';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SizedBox(
            width: Utility.MAX_WIDTH_DESKTOP,
            child: Column(children: [
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60, bottom: 30),
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  assetName,
                  // fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ), // SVG version of logo is looking grainy
              ),
              Container(
                child: const SignInForm(),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Issue seems to be there no matter what SVG file I use. File used here is this one :

```
<svg width="320px" height="320px" viewBox="0 0 320 320" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M171.148 6.55509C142.089 2.42734 120.139 21.7924 109.155 48.9429C104.424 60.6389 100.328 75.1846 97.3187 91.4203C104.447 89.4064 118.553 86.2436 126.153 85.3465C138.897 78.9975 155.975 69.3896 156.683 68.4635C157.555 69.6081 174.747 82.5595 186.145 90.3333C193.076 91.5659 209.707 96.186 212.142 97.3148C212.142 97.3148 216.085 98.8078 221.839 101.036C223.662 101.742 225.667 102.522 227.787 103.351C226.636 101.722 225.532 100.018 224.487 98.2251C222.891 95.4867 221.43 92.5409 220.141 89.3359C215.77 78.4655 215.014 67.479 214.312 57.2828C213.549 46.1996 212.85 36.0501 207.643 27.9983C198.676 14.1337 187.523 8.88131 171.148 6.55509ZM264.522 141.74C263.921 149.231 263.27 157.188 262.799 162.951C262.44 167.335 262.186 170.448 262.136 171.119C262.02 172.668 247.889 170.153 234.651 167.798C223.886 165.883 213.711 164.072 212.142 164.637C210.525 165.218 212.963 185.269 215.709 207.857C218.907 234.166 222.524 263.917 220.641 270.357C218.542 277.535 165.181 275.385 122.053 269.931C126.507 276.579 131.525 282.744 137.152 288.309C158.237 309.163 184.315 317.381 213.642 312.744C246.42 307.562 259.755 275.766 268.952 253.836L269.135 253.402C279.593 228.468 284.528 194.729 274.634 161.644C272.257 153.694 268.717 147.298 264.522 141.74ZM156.649 68.3914C156.711 68.3884 156.721 68.4131 156.683 68.4635C156.655 68.4278 156.644 68.4036 156.649 68.3914Z" fill="#B2AB73"/>
<path d="M93.1571 92.8268C139.903 103.388 165.978 105.084 212.142 97.3149M93.1571 92.8268C93.1571 92.8268 43.1635 116.265 42.1637 120.254C41.1638 124.244 39.4654 159.579 40.1639 162.642C40.8624 165.705 81.1585 162.674 84.6582 164.637C88.1579 166.6 64.1608 244.425 67.6604 256.394C71.16 268.362 217.141 282.325 220.641 270.357C224.14 258.388 208.642 165.895 212.142 164.637C215.641 163.379 261.926 173.927 262.135 171.119C262.345 168.312 266.135 122.748 266.135 120.254C266.135 117.761 212.142 97.3149 212.142 97.3149M93.1571 92.8268C95.4385 91.4983 116.282 86.5118 126.153 85.3466M212.142 97.3149C209.707 96.1861 193.075 91.566 186.145 90.3334M152.649 45.9509C147.689 42.8133 145.657 37.6541 147.15 31.9879C148.669 26.2223 153.215 23.2253 159.149 22.5129C166.196 21.6668 171.295 25.7459 174.647 31.9879C177.781 37.8248 176.527 42.5929 174.647 48.943C171.711 58.8557 156.649 68.3915 156.649 68.3915M156.649 68.3915C157.847 68.3341 139.59 78.652 126.153 85.3466M156.649 68.3915C156.477 68.7951 174.391 82.3171 186.145 90.3334M126.153 85.3466C149.15 85.3466 164.148 87.3413 186.145 90.3334M204.643 110.779C204.643 110.779 219.857 105.292 225.14 97.3149C228.34 92.4836 225.52 86.8582 230.139 83.3519C233.645 80.6912 241.138 80.8585 241.138 80.8585M241.138 80.8585C241.138 80.8585 240.48 88.3387 241.138 89.8347C241.797 91.3307 261.038 92.3281 262.135 90.8321C263.233 89.336 263.635 74.8743 262.635 73.877C261.635 72.8796 243.638 72.8796 242.138 73.877C240.638 74.8743 241.138 80.8585 241.138 80.8585ZM110.655 144.689H117.154M123.653 144.689H117.154M117.154 144.689L112.655 167.629M112.655 167.629H105.656M112.655 167.629H121.154M230.139 130.726C229.923 135.87 229.909 137.95 230.139 139.703M245.637 126.238C245.62 128.765 245.392 130.629 244.138 135.713M244.138 145.687C244.348 148.608 244.313 150.246 244.138 153.167M84.6582 238.94C84.959 242.056 84.9734 243.803 84.6582 246.919M89.6576 251.407C92.2166 252.026 93.7505 252.004 96.6567 251.407M114.654 200.542C114.654 200.542 109.415 191.663 104.156 192.064C99.3359 192.432 97.2286 195.754 96.6567 200.542C95.92 206.709 107.155 208.52 107.155 211.014C107.155 213.009 98.2503 214.528 98.1565 220.489C98.0741 225.728 100.416 228.593 105.656 228.966C112.655 229.465 119.154 218.494 119.154 218.494L166.648 222.982C166.648 222.982 175.147 231.46 180.646 231.46C186.145 231.46 190.61 225.051 188.645 220.489C186.68 215.927 178.646 216.001 178.646 214.006C178.646 212.011 191.129 210.346 189.645 204.032C188.444 198.927 185.4 197.239 180.146 197.051C174.19 196.837 169.647 205.03 169.647 205.03L114.654 200.542ZM162.648 156.658C164.351 156.941 169.844 146.994 175.647 149.676C180.004 151.69 180.203 155.801 179.146 158.154C175.517 166.236 163.377 175.676 163.148 175.608C162.919 175.539 149.496 160.494 147.65 158.154C145.296 155.169 146.324 149.25 151.15 148.18C155.649 147.183 160.945 156.375 162.648 156.658Z" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" stroke-linecap="round"/>
</svg>
```

Any help much appreciated!

**EDIT :** As per @enxaneta 's comment, I tried adding `shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"` to the paths in my SVG file.
No change, but I just realized that ***if I zoom-in broswer to 120%***, the SVG is now looking good.

This is still not ideal, since most users would probably have their Zoom at 100%.

Comment: You may try to use `shape-rendering="geometricPrecision"`. Also if you intend to stretch the drawing you may try to remove the width and height attributes of the svg element.

Comment: try load your svg into https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/  ... optimize it... use optimized svg ...

Comment: @enxaneta It seems like the `shape-rendering` doesn't change anything.
_However_ I realized that if I zoom-in broswer to 120%, svg is now looking crisp.